# Read request message body while binding dependency using ninject.extensions.wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am using Ninject.Extensions.Wcf in a WCF service, and also have the Ninject.Web.Common package in my project.

In the NinjectWebCommon class this is how I bind my dependency

```
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<ConcreteSomething>();
```

straightforward binding, and everything works..

Now, I want to do the resolution based on some members in the message request body, so I create a provider

```
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().ToProvider<SomethingProvider>();
```

And SomethingProvider tries to read the request message like this

```
public class SomethingProvider : Provider<ISomething>
{
    protected override ISomething CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var message = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
        //message.State is Read here, so CreateBufferedCopy throws an InvalidOperationException.

        var buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        message = buffer.CreateMessage();
        var messageCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
        var body = messageCopy.GetBody<string>();

        //Parse body, check some members and return one of the "Somethings"
        return new AnotherConcreteSomething();
    }
}
```

This throws an invalid operation exception. The RequestMessage in the operationcontext is already in read state, so I cant read it again.

I read that RequestMessage.ToString() is not always reliable since it truncates the body. And, I will have to get the body from the whole SOAP message.

Is there any other way I can do this? Is this approach even correct?